# .htaccess RewriteRule working for some works, throwing a 404 for others

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have written the following Rewrite Rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^add-post/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/$ add_post.php?thread_id=$1thread_name=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search/?s=([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/$ search.php?s=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/$ lvl1_forum.php?forum=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/$ lvl2_thread.php?forum=$1&thread_id=$2&thread_title=$3 [NC,L]
```

The rule is working for all of the pages, except for add_post.php (which exists). I've tried the .htaccess with the Options line at the top of the file and below the RewriteEngine on rule but no dice.

How can I modify this file to make the add-post rule work?

Comment: Could you please specify source url and expected redirects examples ?

Comment: Plus i'm not sure your search uri will work neither cause you're trying to parse the query string in the `rewriteRule` instead of a `rewriteCond`.

Comment: Are you sure it works with the *search* rewrite? It shouldn't since, as @FlorianLemaitre points out, RewriteRule doesn't match on the querystring without a `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ... ` condition first : see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: You are very right! It doesn't work on search (well, the page loads at least but the query part doesn't function). With the add-post, I get a complete 404 error. That's the difference between the two. Sorry about that!

Comment: Okay, I solved it. Of course, it was a silly little error. In this case, I didn't have a slash at the end of my link. Everything is working now. Thank you!